# Add Colour Gradient to Circular Progress Bar iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer, cashapelayer

I am having difficulty adding a colour gradient to my circular progress bar

[image]

My setup:

1. Storyboard: ViewController with an empty view designated as the Class CircularProgressBar
2. Custom class for the CircularProgressBar

Steps Taken:

1. I am able to load circular progress bar
2. In earlier attempts I created a gradient shape layer & set it to be masked by the bounds of the BarLayer, however the gradient shape layer draw a rectangle starting from the centre of my circle & extend to the bottom right so only that portion of the BarLayer would have a gradient
3. When I moved the origin of the gradient layer rectangle it shifted the Barlayer off the TrackLayer with it

How do I:

Have the gradient layer cover the entire circular progress bar & mask it to the BarLayer

```
class CircularProgressBar: UIView {

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)
    addProgressBar(radius: 5, progress: 0)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addProgressBar(radius: 5, progress: 0)
}

func addProgressBar(radius: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat) {

    let lineWidth = radius*0.080

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, clockwise: true)

    //TrackLayer
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.opacity = 0.5
    trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    trackLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round

    //BarLayer
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round



    //Rotate Shape Layer
    shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)

//Shape Shadow
    shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -7, height: 7)
    shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 1
    shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

    //Animation
    loadProgress(percentage: progress)

    //LoadLayers
    layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}  
func loadProgress(percentage: CGFloat) {

    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.fromValue = 0
    basicAnimation.duration = 2
    basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = percentage
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "basicStroke")

}
```

ViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!


var circularProgressBar = CircularProgressBar()
var radius: CGFloat!
var progress: CGFloat!

var answeredCorrect = 0
var totalQuestions = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    answeredCorrect = 50
    totalQuestions = 100

    //Configure Progress Bar
    radius = (containerView.frame.height)/2.60
    progress = CGFloat(answeredCorrect) / CGFloat (totalQuestions)
    circularProgressBar.addProgressBar(radius: radius, progress: progress)
    circularProgressBar.center = containerView.center

    //Adding view
    containerView.addSubview(circularProgressBar)


}  
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve ? please show final image

Comment: what you achieved , and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something like this

[image]

You need to update your code

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class CircularProgressBar: UIView {

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)
   // addProgressBar(radius: 50, progress: 50)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   // addProgressBar(radius: 50, progress: 50)
}
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    addProgressBar(radius: 50, progress: 50)
  }
func addProgressBar(radius: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat) {

  let lineWidth = CGFloat(10.0)//radius*0.080

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, clockwise: true)

    //TrackLayer
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    trackLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round

    //BarLayer
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth*2
    //shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round

    //Rotate Shape Layer
   // shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)

    //Animation
   // loadProgress(percentage: progress)

    //LoadLayers
   layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
   self.addGradient()

  // layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}

  private func addGradient() {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.purple.cgColor,UIColor.systemPink.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.mask = shapeLayer
    layer.addSublayer(gradient)
  }
}
```

And for Uniform gradient you can replace addGradient method

[image]

```
private func addGradient() {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.cyan.cgColor,UIColor.brown.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.locations = [0.2,0.5,0.75,1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradient.type = .conic
    gradient.mask = shapeLayer
    layer.addSublayer(gradient)
  }
```

Comment: Hey jawadAli, thank you again for your answers. I added a pictures of the progress bar (the gradient would be from dark green on the top to light green on the bottom) as well as some animation code for it to load as soon as the view controller appears.

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to my View Controller Code?

Comment: `loadProgress(percentage: progress)` update this method i questionn

Comment: Will do, added the animation code just under the addSublayers code in the first code box as a separate function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213549/discussion-between-jawadali-and-captain725).